# Is it okay to use my German Schengen visa to enter Austria for study until residence permit is issued?

Tags: schengen, study, austria, change-purpose-of-travel

I have a 2-year Schengen type C visa issued by Germany to visit my sibling who studies there. I wanted to know if it's okay to use this visa to enter Austria to start my university studies. I already entered Germany a couple of times and used it to enter France and Greece twice.

I will not exceed 90 days and I have already applied to the residence permit. Will there be a problem to use that visa?

Answer (score 1):

The first trip with a multiple entry visa should be for the purpose from the application. The following trips can have other purposes. There will be no problem if you **visit** Austria now and look at a city where you might want to study.

As I understand it, you cannot apply for the residence permit while you are in Austria. You have already applied and the decision is pending, and I don't know if they just check your residence at the time of application. For details on that, better ask on [Expatriates Stack Exchange](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yes I already fulfilled the purpose of the application in the first trip. I have already got accepted in university and waiting fir the acceptance of my residence permit. But it will take 3 months for the acceptance to come and my studies start end of this month. So is it okay to use that visa I have till the residence permit is issued?

Comment: @Faresmetwally, ask on Expatriates. I have some doubts that going to university is covered by your visa.